# Why the extended complex plane $\mathbb{C_\infty} = \mathbb{C}\cup \{\infty\}$ is compact while $\mathbb{C}$ is not?

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, compactness, complex-dynamics

I think this is due to the fact the extended complex plane can be stereographically identified with the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R^3}$.

However, an exact and proper explanation is required.

Comment: You should read about one-point compactifications, if you want a purely topological explanation.

Comment: Using the stereographic identification, you see that the extended complex plane is an image of a compact set under a continuous map.

Comment: If you know that both $\mathbb C$ and $\mathbb C_{\infty}$ are metrisable, then this is clear: any sequence in $\mathbb C$ is either bounded, or has a subsequence tending to $\infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called the one-point compactification and it is used to make a non-compact topological space, compact. Is is done in the following manner:

First, let $X$ be a noncompact topological space, and $\infty \notin X$, we construct a the space $X'=X\cup \{\infty\}$ and endow it with the cofinite topology, i.e. the topology is $$\tau = \tau_X\cup \{U\cup \{\infty \}: U \text{ is open in $X$ and }|X\setminus U|<\omega \}$$
Where $\tau_X$ is the original topology on $X$, clearly $\tau \supset \tau_X$, nevertheless consider and open cover $\mathcal{U}$, there exist some $U\in \mathcal{U}$ such that $\infty \in U$, then $X\setminus U$ must be finite, For each $x\in X\setminus U$ choose one $V_x\in \mathcal{U}$ such that $x\in V_x$ consider now the collection of sets  $\{V_x : x\in X\setminus U \}\cup \{ U\}$ is a finite open cover of $X'$. Thus we conclude $X'$ is compact. This is the general case, in your particular question $\mathbb{C}_\infty=X'$ and $\mathbb{C}=X$

Comment: When I say finity open cover, I really mean finite subcover... Just to make myself clear, also, in the 2nd line I mean ¨It is done¨ instead of Is is done

Answer (score 2):

Topologically, $\{B(0,R) : R>0\}$ is an open cover of $\mathbb{C}$ which does not have a finite subcover, but it is not an open cover of $\mathbb{C}_\infty$.

Comment: This does not explain why $\mathbb C_{\infty}$ is compact though...

Comment: True, but in the question OP notes that $\mathbb{C}_{\infty}$ can be identified with the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^3$, and @HuangSamuel points out in the comments that this is a valid approach.

Comment: I think $\Bbb{C} \cup \infty$ is compact because of its two charts $f(z)=z, g(z) = 1/z$ saying it is covered by two compacts $f(|z| \le 2)$ and $g(|z| \le 2)$. Without the data of such a chart then it can be $\Bbb{C} \ \cup $ an external isolated point which is not compact